# ZeroDivisionError: division by zero error,py

Tags: python, division

I ran the following code and expected to get division in the last print statement but got error.
Here are my code

```
**a=1
b="2"
c=87
print(int(7.5))
print(str(a)+b)
print(c/0)**
```

and error message here

```
**File "C:\Users\Parm\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\Programing Error and Fixing\error.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(c/0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero**
```

Comment: Why are you surprised by this?  You are dividing by zero, and that's an error.

Comment: It is working as expected ([see Python documentation on the error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ZeroDivisionError)). A division by zero is neither computationally nor mathematically defined.

Answer (score 0):

before you ask here on the forums, it is a good idea to research online. In this case, you would have found that dividing by zero is mathematically impossible. Also, next time, add more detail on what exactly you are trying to do. But thank you for contributing.